cannot import name 'default_decompositions' from 'torch.export' (Pytorch & Executorch issues)
I am trying to serve Llama 3.2 1B spinquant on my iPhone using executorch, but I am encountering errors. (macOS Sequoia 15.1, macbook Air m1 ram16gb, anaconda environment user)
ImportError: cannot import name 'default_decompositions' from 'torch.export' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/export/__init__.py)

Let me explain the situation in detail.
https://github.com/pytorch/executorch/blob/main/examples/demo-apps/apple_ios/LLaMA/docs/delegates/xnnpack_README.md
Setup ExecuTorch
In this section, we will need to set up the ExecuTorch repo first with Conda environment management. Make sure you have Conda available in your system (or follow the instructions to install it here). The commands below are running on Linux (CentOS).
Create a Conda environment
conda create -n et_xnnpack python=3.10.0
conda activate et_xnnpack

Checkout ExecuTorch repo and sync submodules
git clone https://github.com/pytorch/executorch.git
cd executorch
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init

Install dependencies
./install_requirements.sh

I was able to proceed without major issues up to this point. The problem arose in the next part, where I needed to input the paths corresponding to the model.
For Llama 3.2 1B and 3B SpinQuant models
Meta has released prequantized INT4 SpinQuant Llama 3.2 models that ExecuTorch supports on the XNNPACK backend.
Export Llama model and generate .pte file as below:
python -m examples.models.llama.export_llama --model "llama3_2" --checkpoint <path-to-your-checkpoint.pth> --params <path-to-your-params.json> -kv --use_sdpa_with_kv_cache -X -d fp32 --xnnpack-extended-ops --preq_mode 8da4w_output_8da8w --preq_group_size 32 --max_seq_length 2048 --preq_embedding_quantize 8,0 --use_spin_quant native --metadata '{"get_bos_id":128000, "get_eos_ids":[128009, 128001]}' --output_name "llama3_2_spinquant.pte"

Errors arose in these codes.
(et_xnnpack) questionone@curious-MacBookAir executorch % python -m examples.models.llama.export_llama \
  --model "llama3_2" \
  --checkpoint "/Users/questionone/.llama/checkpoints/Llama3.2-1B-Instruct-int4-spinquant-eo8/consolidated.00.pth" \
  --params "/Users/questionone/.llama/checkpoints/Llama3.2-1B-Instruct-int4-spinquant-eo8/params.json" \
  -kv \
  --use_sdpa_with_kv_cache \
  -X \
  -d fp32 \
  --xnnpack-extended-ops \
  --preq_mode 8da4w_output_8da8w \
  --preq_group_size 32 \
  --max_seq_length 2048 \
  --preq_embedding_quantize 8,0 \
  --use_spin_quant native \
  --metadata '{"get_bos_id":128000, "get_eos_ids":[128009, 128001]}' \
  --output_name "llama3_2_spinquant.pte"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/Users/questionone/executorch/examples/models/llama/export_llama.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .export_llama_lib import build_args_parser, export_llama
  File "/Users/questionone/executorch/examples/models/llama/export_llama_lib.py", line 25, in <module>
    from executorch.devtools.etrecord import generate_etrecord
  File "/Users/questionone/executorch/devtools/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import executorch.devtools.inspector as inspector
  File "/Users/questionone/executorch/devtools/inspector/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from executorch.devtools.inspector._inspector import (
  File "/Users/questionone/executorch/devtools/inspector/_inspector.py", line 31, in <module>
    import executorch.devtools.etdump.schema_flatcc as flatcc
  File "/Users/questionone/executorch/devtools/etdump/schema_flatcc.py", line 18, in <module>
    from executorch.exir.scalar_type import ScalarType
  File "/Users/questionone/executorch/exir/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from executorch.exir.capture import (
  File "/Users/questionone/executorch/exir/capture/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from executorch.exir.capture._capture import (
  File "/Users/questionone/executorch/exir/capture/_capture.py", line 15, in <module>
    from executorch.exir.capture._config import CaptureConfig
  File "/Users/questionone/executorch/exir/capture/_config.py", line 15, in <module>
    from executorch.exir.passes import MemoryPlanningPass, ToOutVarPass
  File "/Users/questionone/executorch/exir/passes/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from executorch.exir import control_flow, memory, memory_planning
  File "/Users/questionone/executorch/exir/control_flow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from executorch.exir.tracer import (
  File "/Users/questionone/executorch/exir/tracer.py", line 50, in <module>
    from torch.export import default_decompositions
ImportError: cannot import name 'default_decompositions' from 'torch.export' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/export/__init__.py)


I would like to know why these errors are occurring. Executorch and PyTorch are already installed in the environment called et_xnnpack.
Even after resetting the path with the command export PYTHONPATH=/Users/questionone/executorch, the errors persist.
+
(et_xnnpack) questionone@curious-MacBookAir executorch % conda list -n et_xnnpack
# packages in environment at /opt/anaconda3/envs/et_xnnpack:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
annotated-types           0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
anyio                     4.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     24.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                    openblas  
blobfile                  3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
bzip2                     1.0.8                h80987f9_6  
ca-certificates           2024.11.26           hca03da5_0  
certifi                   2024.12.14               pypi_0    pypi
charset-normalizer        3.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
click                     8.1.8                    pypi_0    pypi
cmake                     3.31.2                   pypi_0    pypi
distro                    1.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
exceptiongroup            1.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
execnet                   2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
executorch                0.5.0a0+82763a9          pypi_0    pypi
expecttest                0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
filelock                  3.16.1                   pypi_0    pypi
fire                      0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
flatbuffers               24.3.25                  pypi_0    pypi
fsspec                    2024.12.0                pypi_0    pypi
gmp                       6.2.1                hc377ac9_3  
gmpy2                     2.1.2           py310h8c48613_0  
h11                       0.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
httpcore                  1.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
httpx                     0.28.1                   pypi_0    pypi
huggingface-hub           0.27.0                   pypi_0    pypi
hypothesis                6.123.0                  pypi_0    pypi
idna                      3.10                     pypi_0    pypi
iniconfig                 2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jinja2                    3.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
libabseil                 20240116.2      cxx17_h313beb8_0  
libcxx                    14.0.6               h848a8c0_0  
libffi                    3.4.4                hca03da5_1  
libgfortran               5.0.0           11_3_0_hca03da5_28  
libgfortran5              11.3.0              h009349e_28  
libopenblas               0.3.21               h269037a_0  
libprotobuf               4.25.3               h514c7bf_0  
llama-models              0.0.63                   pypi_0    pypi
llama-stack               0.0.63                   pypi_0    pypi
llama-stack-client        0.0.63                   pypi_0    pypi
llvm-openmp               14.0.6               hc6e5704_0  
lxml                      5.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
markdown-it-py            3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                3.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mdurl                     0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mpc                       1.1.0                h8c48613_1  
mpfr                      4.0.2                h695f6f0_1  
mpmath                    1.3.0           py310hca03da5_0  
ncurses                   6.4                  h313beb8_0  
networkx                  3.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.21.3                   pypi_0    pypi
numpy-base                1.26.4          py310ha9811e2_0  
openssl                   3.0.15               h80987f9_0  
packaging                 24.2                     pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    2.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
parameterized             0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    11.0.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pip                       24.2            py310hca03da5_0  
pluggy                    1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
prompt-toolkit            3.0.48                   pypi_0    pypi
pyaml                     24.12.1                  pypi_0    pypi
pycryptodomex             3.21.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pydantic                  2.10.4                   pypi_0    pypi
pydantic-core             2.27.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pytest                    8.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
pytest-xdist              3.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.10.16              hb885b13_1  
python-dateutil           2.9.0.post0              pypi_0    pypi
python-dotenv             1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pytorch                   2.3.1           gpu_mps_py310h7b7e308_100  
pytz                      2024.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    6.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.2                  h1a28f6b_0  
regex                     2024.11.6                pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.32.3                   pypi_0    pypi
rich                      13.9.4                   pypi_0    pypi
ruamel-yaml               0.18.6                   pypi_0    pypi
ruamel-yaml-clib          0.2.12                   pypi_0    pypi
safetensors               0.4.5                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                75.1.0          py310hca03da5_0  
six                       1.17.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sleef                     3.5.1                h80987f9_2  
sniffio                   1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sortedcontainers          2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.45.3               h80987f9_0  
sympy                     1.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tabulate                  0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 2.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tiktoken                  0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
timm                      1.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.14               h6ba3021_0  
tokenizers                0.20.3                   pypi_0    pypi
tomli                     2.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
torch                     2.6.0.dev20241218          pypi_0    pypi
torchaudio                2.6.0.dev20241218          pypi_0    pypi
torchsr                   1.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.22.0.dev20241218          pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.67.1                   pypi_0    pypi
transformers              4.46.1                   pypi_0    pypi
typing_extensions         4.12.2          py310hca03da5_0  
tzdata                    2024.2                   pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.2.13                   pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.44.0          py310hca03da5_0  
xz                        5.4.6                h80987f9_1  
zlib                      1.2.13               h18a0788_1  
zstd                      1.5.5.1                  pypi_0    pypi


Change the import to "from functorch.compile import default_decompositions"
